# Access Serial port with Python on Raspberry Pi3

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, serial

I have been trying to make serial work with Python and Pi3, however so far I have been unsuccessful.

When running the Python script, I am getting an error "serial.serialutil.SerialException: Port is already open."

I have already tried all tips in another post that should solve issues with Pi3 and the Bluetooth port.
([How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3))

My python script is the following:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 9600, timeout=1)
ser.open()

ser.write("testing")
try:
    while 1:
        response = ser.readline()
        print response
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ser.close()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Er, yes.  The error will show the line in error.  Remove it.

Comment: @joan, the line which throws the error is line 3:  ser.open()

Comment: That's the line you need to remove.

Comment: What happens if you run `lsof`?

Comment: @Bex serial.Serial() opens the device if the device is specified.  The ser.open() call is trying to re-open an already opened device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 9600, timeout=1)` opens the device automatically.  When you try to open the device that is already open, python raises an error.  Just take out `ser.open()` and it will work.